# Two indefinite integrals with the same derivative

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> Two indefinite integrals with the same derivative lead to the same family of curves and so they are equivalent

quoting from my calculus book. ie.
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)dx=\frac{d}{dx}\int g(x)dx\implies\int f(x)dx\text{ and }\int g(x)dx\text{ are equivalent.}
$$
This makes sense as if the derivative of two functions is equal then the functions are separated by a constant. But, using the property $\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)dx=f(x)$, it seems to conclude that $f(x)=g(x)$

What am I missing here ?

Comment: I suppose you mean $\int^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ rather than $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx$? And yes, this condition does conclude that $f=g$, i.e. that the slope of the two functions given by $\int^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ and $\int^x g(t)\,\mathrm dt$ are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything.

$$\int f(x)dx$$ simply means an antiderivative of $f(x).$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)dx=\frac{d}{dx}\int g(x)dx\implies\int f(x)dx =\int g(x)dx +C$$

where C is a constant.

Also,

$$\frac {d}{dx}\int f(x)dx=\frac{d}{dx}\int g(x)dx \implies f(x)=g(x)$$

Comment: u mean if $\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)dx=\frac{d}{dx}\int g(x)dx\implies$$\int f(x)dx$ and $\int g(x)dx$ belongs to same family of curves. And $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same functions.right ?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

$\int f(x)dx$ and $\int g(x)dx$ are "families." When $\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int g(x)$ then we can say that functions in the family $\int f(x)dx$ are the same as the functions in the family $\int g(x)dx$. This doesn't mean that $f(x)=g(x)$. Take the case $g(x)=f(x)+1$ for example.